# Why $ \int_0^{-x} f(t)\, dt $ equals to $\int_0^x f(-u)\, d(-u)$ instead of $\int_0^{-x} f(-u)\, d(-u)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I know it may be a either naive or bad question, but please do not close it because this is my last choice after having thought on it for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with, as proposed,

$$\int_0^{-x} f(t)dt$$

Make the $u$ substitution $u=-t$ (equivalently, $t=-u$). Then $dt=-du=d(-u)$. Bear in mind that $u$ substitution basically amounts to defining a second function through which we might manipulate the integral into something else, with emphasis on "function." Thus, while you might often see $u=-t$ as in this example, it might make more sense to instead state $u$ as a function of $t$: in this case, we would have $u(t)=-t$.

This idea of $u$ being a function is important when we change the bounds of integration. To get the bounds adjusted, evaluate our substitution at each bound: $u(0) = -(0)=0$, and $u(-x) = -(-x) = x$. Thus,

$$\int_0^{-x} f(t)dt = \int_{u(0)}^{u(-x)} f(-u)d(-u) = \int_0^x f(-u)d(-u)$$

Comment: Great explanation. I might emphasize that $u$ is a function of $t$ so $u(t)=-t$ which clarifies what it means for $u(-x)=x$

Comment: but $\int_a^b s\,\mathrm{d}(blah)$ usually means the limits are blah=a (or b), not blob=a for some other blob, even if implicitly blah is a function of blob.